# How to dynamically align an ImageView to centre of Constraint Layout?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I am trying to align an image view to centre of constraint layout. I am writing below code but its not working.

**Code**

```
int size = 150;
ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(size, size);

layoutParams.bottomToBottom = ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID;
layoutParams.endToEnd = ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID;
layoutParams.startToStart = ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID;
layoutParams.topToTop = ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID;

circleImageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Comment: Can you share your layout?

Comment: you need to clone the previous constraintlayout.layoutparams while making the new one. Also make sure your imageview has height and width of 0dp

Answer (score 11):

ConstraintLayout cLayout = findViewById(R.id.main_layout);

```
        TextView ev = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        ev.setText(getString(R.string.not_found_name));
        ev.setTextSize(50);
        ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams( ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        layoutParams.bottomToBottom = ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID;
        layoutParams.endToEnd = ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID;
        layoutParams.startToStart = ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID;
        layoutParams.topToTop = ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID;

        ev.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        cLayout.addView(ev);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this, with the use of **ConstraintSet** you can easily render view programatically into center in **ConstraintLayout**.

```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
    imageView.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    imageView.setId(R.id.imageview);

    ConstraintLayout myLayout = new ConstraintLayout(this);
    myLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);

    myLayout.addView(imageView);
    setContentView(myLayout);

    ConstraintSet set = new ConstraintSet();

    set.constrainHeight(imageView.getId(),
            ConstraintSet.WRAP_CONTENT);
    set.constrainWidth(imageView.getId(),
            ConstraintSet.WRAP_CONTENT);

    set.connect(imageView.getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT,
            ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.LEFT, 0);
    set.connect(imageView.getId(), ConstraintSet.RIGHT,
            ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.RIGHT, 0);
    set.connect(imageView.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP,
            ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.TOP, 0);
    set.connect(imageView.getId(), ConstraintSet.BOTTOM,
            ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, 0);

    set.applyTo(myLayout);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

in your code:

```
ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID
```

is not the real ID of parent constraint layout. You need to change it to:

```
R.id.myLayout
```

in which myLayout is what you type in the *.xml file:

```
android:id="@+id/myLayout"
```

this should work:

```
int size = 150;
ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(size, size);

layoutParams.topToTop = R.id.myLayout;
layoutParams.bottomToBottom = R.id.myLayout;
layoutParams.leftToLeft = R.id.myLayout;
layoutParams.rightToRight = R.id.myLayout;
layoutParams.verticalBias = (float) 0.95;
layoutParams.horizontalBias = (float) 0.5;

circleImageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```